# how to call c++/cli constructor in c# and how to include the dlls of cli

Tags: c#, c++-cli

i have a c++/cli class having a constructor and destructor and method name requirement. i need to call this method in c# wcf program, so this is what i did in c# wcf code for calling c++/cli method.

```
Class1 test= new Class1();
test.requirment();
```

my question is that how does the c# program knows that which c++/cli program it is referring to and i added this cli dll as a reference to the c# wcf program and also used it as a namespace. So i want to know like what i am doing is correct or not, and also want to know whether is there any other way to do this or any other settings need to be changed in c# program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could only do slightly better as you're already doing. If your C++/CLI class contains some native resources (usually the only reason to use C++/CLI) and you've properly implemented the C++/CLI "destructor" i.e. `~Class1()` method:

```
using (var test1 = new Class1()) {
    test1.requirement();
}
```

This works because each C++/CLI class implements `IDisposable` by default and maps `~Class1()` to an implementation of `Dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

This is defined by your project references (right-click the project -> Add References...). If the C++/CLI project is in the same solution, you should add it under the "Projects" tab, otherwise select "Browse" and select the C++/CLI assembly on the file system.

C++/CLI projects and assemblies are no different in this regard than any other .NET project or assembly.

To make sure that the identifier "Class1" in your code refers to the correct type, you can use Go To Definition and it should show you where the type is defined. If there is an ambiguity or missing reference the code will not compile anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct in my opinion and you dont need to do anything else. Make sure that Class1 is declared as a Managed class in the C++/CLI assembly (public ref class Class1), and you are good to go.

Since you have added the C++/CLI assembly as reference to the assembly that has the WPF code, and also added the namespace in using clause, the runtime and compiler has enough information to resolve the things.